# Add Existing Node As Child with Node Module

Tags: nodes

I am currently using the [node collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_collection) module to build parent/child relationships, but I have a lot of existing content that does not already have the parent/child relationship in place.

Is there a way to add the parent/child relationship after the content is created using this module?

I've checked the documentation and looked at the module settings, but I couldn't find a good solution.